# require-handlebars-plugin build error - ReferenceError: _ is not defined

Tags: javascript, requirejs, handlebars.js

I'm trying to build a requirejs/backbone/handlebars project, and I seem to be coming accross this error when I try run the app.build.js:

```
Tracing dependencies for: main
ReferenceError: _ is not defined
In module tree:
    main
      cs
        hbs
          underscore

ReferenceError: _ is not defined
In module tree:
    main
      cs
        hbs
          underscore

    at Object.eval (eval at <anonymous> (/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:13718:64))
```

The app works perfectly in and without errors when not built. The project has backbone and underscore included as requirejs shims if it matters. I would post the whole source, but it is an internal system, so I can't. If more info is needed, I can post it.

Thanks!

Comment: sounds like it doesn't see _.js

Comment: @kennypu yeah It mustn't, but I don't know why - it's seeing it when I run it in the browser.

Comment: Backbone requires Underscore, Underscore defines `_`.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware. It's not backbone that's complaining though. It's just buggering up on the hbs file I think. The dependency works fine in the browser (not compiled with r.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and this worked for me -

Remove underscore from your RequireJS shim.

Then at the bottom of your underscore.js file, just above the closing brackets and call statement, add a define statement to properly export _

```
  define(function(){
        return _;
    });

}).call(this);
```